# reCaptcha GET / POST

Tags: php, curl, post, recaptcha

I'm going through a small list upgrading things on the parts of my web system I have already done, one of which is ensuring that the security of my Google reCaptcha is correct.

Currently, I use this code:

```
//reCaptcha
$Url = "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify";
$SecretKey = "----Secret Key----";
$Response = file_get_contents($Url."?secret=".$SecretKey."&response=".$_POST['Response']);
$Robot = json_decode($Response);
```

This works fine, however Google's documentation says you should use the POST method instead of get, obviously to ensure someone does not get hold of my secret key. I'm unsure on how to do this, however, so some guidance would be appreciated. I understand I will likely have to use cURL, however, I have no knowledge in it and I am unsure on how to install it (if that's required).

Thanks, Tom.

Comment: To POST the variables to Google's reCaptcha server instead of sending them via GET.

Comment: But it never sends the variables using `$_GET`, it always sends them using `$_POST`. See the documentation here, [https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/verify](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/verify). By the way, `$_POST['Response']` is wrong, it should be `$_POST['g-recaptcha-response']`.

Comment: @RajdeepPaul `$_POST['Reponse']` is correct as it's actually retrieving the variable through an Ajax call, in which you cannot post variables with a "-" in the name. In reference to the POST, it says the method of sending should be post, however does that mean it will automatically remove the variables from the URL and POST them instead. I kind of doubt that as from the code I'm using I'm adding the variables into the URL as if it was a GET.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the jQuery/AJAX code as well. From the current code it's unclear what exactly you're trying to do.

Comment: @RajdeepPaul, it's quite clear what I'm asking. I need to know how to POST variables to Google's reCaptcha and that's all. As I clearly stated in my question everything works currently, but is not likely to be secure, so suggesting any other "fixes" besides how to POST variables to reCaptcha is pointless.

Comment: *I need to know how to POST variables to Google's reCaptcha and that's all.*, you're already doing it, see `$.post(...);` and `...&response=".$_POST['Response']);`.

Comment: The first bit is from the AJAX call to posts variables securely from the registration page to a PHP file with a script in. The second bit retrieves /  "catches" the variable sent by the AJAX for use in the PHP script / file to append to the URL. Neither of these relate to POSTing variables to the reCaptcha server.

Comment: Oh, now I understood your question. You want to send user inputted reCaptcha data to the server using GET, right? I believe that's not possible, at least the documentation doesn't say anything such, plus you can't modify the data submission method on the go.

Comment: Not using GET, but using POST. I currently use GET, however this means that the secret key can be seen as it is placed into the URL, which isn't ideal for security as it means that certain checks could be bypassed, etc. It's called a secret key for a reason :)

Comment: First of all, you are not sending any private/secret key(embedded in the URL)to the Google server, it's the public key of domain which you're sending to Google server along with the user inputted data. You will **only** use the private/secret key to verify user's response, just it. And second, it makes no difference if your public key is being sent via GET or POST request, it's already available in the public domain, that's why it's called public key.

Comment: @RajdeepPaul here is validating the response from the user's web browser when they complete the reCaptcha. The system does the public key and initial check and the piece of code I have shown collects the response from the web client before sending it to the reCaptcha server with the secret key to validate it is indeed correct. This is server side, rather than client side. The secret key certainly isn't in public domain and shouldn't be, the documentation does specifically highlight that.

Comment: I think I understood your point correctly, and hence I rolled this question back to revision 1. Also, I've given an answer below, hopefully this will resolve your issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ... POST the variables to Google's reCaptcha server instead of sending them via GET.
>
> ```
> $Response = file_get_contents($Url."?secret=".$SecretKey."&response=".$_POST['Response']);
> ```

Instead of embedding the data in the URL(like the secret key and the response in the above URL) and sending it via GET, if you want to send the data to Google server via HTTP POST then you have to use client URL library.

Here's the reference:

- http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

Your server side PHP code should be like this:

```
$Url = "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify";
$SecretKey = "----Secret Key----";
if(isset($_POST['Response']) && !empty($_POST['Response'])){
    //get verified response data
    $data = array('secret' => $secret, 'response' => $_POST['Response']);

    $ch = curl_init($Url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);  
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));
    $verifyResponse = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    
    $responseData = json_decode($verifyResponse);
    
    // your code
    
}else{
    echo "Please click on the reCAPTCHA box.";
}
```

---

There are few points to note here,

- Set `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` to `true` to return the transfer as a string of the return value of `curl_exec()` instead of outputting it out directly.
- `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER` can be used to verify peer's certificate. If we specify it as `false`, it will accept any server(peer) certificate.
- `CURLOPT_POST` is used to do regular HTTP POST. This POST is the normal `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` kind, most commonly used by HTML forms.
- `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` is used to specify full data we want to submit with this POST request. The `$data` array should be converted to URL-encoded query string using [`http_build_query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) function, so that it could be sent as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

Comment: variable mis-match for $secret in the array and $secretkey